# How to find list of co-ordinates of a line in an image using android

Tags: android, opencv, coordinates, android-canvas

We have `canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);` method to draw a line from starting position to ending position. How can we retrieve the list of corresponding coordinates(X, Y), through which the line is drawn?[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mdfc.png)

Comment: They usually use "Bresenham's line algorithm" to draw the line so you can use the same algorithm to get that list of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There is not going to be a direct method in OpenCV for this. But the points falling on a line ca be easily calculated using the line equation as:

1. The general equation for line is `y=mx+c`
2. Using the `(start_x, start_y)` and `(end_x, end_y)` we can deduce the values for `m` and `c`.
3. Then we can iterate over `[start_x, end_x]`, place the x, m, and c values to get all the cooresponding y values.